# USB 3 drivers gone - won't install ("The Asmedia USB Host Controller was not found.")

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, drivers, usb-3

My USB 3 drivers are gone, ports only provide power, tried installing from the official asus page for my (old) motherboard, and get the message in the title. My device list looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yt11.png).

I've tried updating the drivers through windows, as well as removing the 'USB Root' devices completely and restarting. Can't find the 'USB Host Controller' as a separate drivers anywhere online so I really don't know where to go from here.

MB: asus pz68-v
OS: Win 10

Drivers I attempted installing was from here: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68V/HelpDesk_Download/

I installed it a while back when I realized my the USB 3 was not functioning and it worked, then after a restart (or a few, didn't notice till a few days ago) the driver was no more.

Comment: You don't seem to have such a device. You can't install drivers for a device that doesn't exists, unless you do it in legacy mode. Windows 10 does have new.functions about drivers and it deletes them after some time, it seems, but here I believe the problem comes from your new motherboard or BIOS.

Comment: Pretty sure those drivers are all just built into Windows 10 and should not need to be loaded separately... I would look in the BIOS and make sure your USB is enabled, but it is possible the USB chipset has failed. The USB ports are providing power but not seeing any devices? Have you tried booting a live Linux distro (a great troubleshooting tool) and see if the USB ports are seen there?

Comment: When I was suggesting a live Linux distribution as a great troubleshooting tool at this forum, everyone laughed at me. Better late then never I guess.        Try these drivers and an Ubuntu Live USB https://www.usb3-drivers.com/asmedia-usb3-drivers.html         The different windows 10 versions have a different access to the driver server. Home gets the least drivers.

Comment: Not that this helps.. but I too made this mistake once.  I had crappy USB3 performance and deleted the controller hoping that it would re-install.  After proving to myself that everything worked (with a linux live distro as @CFCBazar_com points out).  After days of trying, I reinstalled windows.  Everything was back.  I have even written windows device drivers (to include USB).. windows *should* be showing that there is a PNP device ID that doesn't have a driver but JUST LIKE YOU.. NOTHING.  I hope you figure this out.